# useParams not working when using <Route render={ ( ) => <ABC /> } /> instead of <Route component={ ABC } />

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a Route which contains some url params but they only work when <Route component={ ABC } /> and does not work <Route render = { () =>  } />. I want to use the render one since I am passing some props.

```
<Route path="/:param" render = { () => <ABC type="some prop"/> } // useParams or match doesnt work
<Route path="/:param" component= {ABC} // useParams and match both work but I cannot pass in 'type' prop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass route props from the render.

```
<Route path="/:param" render = { (props) => <ABC {...props} type="some prop"/> } />
```

Comment: Can u explain a little why we pass props as an arg and then pass it again as {...props} in ABC component ? I am new to react .

Comment: Read it.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func


`This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop`